# Robotframework : Takescreenshot FAIL RobotNotRunningError: Cannot access execution context

Tags: python, robotframework

When using Robot framework remotelibrary/SAPguilibrary to handle SAP desktop app using Takescreenshot keyword fail

```
from robotremoteserver import RobotRemoteServer
from SapGuiLibrary import SapGuiLibrary
from robotremoteserver import Screenshot

server = RobotRemoteServer(SapGuiLibrary(), host='192.168.101.20', port=39444, serve=False)
server.serve()
```

Takescreenshot should work.

I'm having this : KEYWORD Remote_SapGuiLibrary. Take Screenshot

Documentation:

Takes a screenshot, only if 'screenshots on error' has been enabled, either at import of with keyword `enable screenshots on error`.

Start / End / Elapsed:

20190722 16:42:16.621 / 20190722 16:42:16.625 / 00:00:00.004

16:42:16.625

FAIL

**RobotNotRunningError: Cannot access execution context**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use built-in keywords in keywords that are running in a remote library. Like the error says, the remote library doesn't have access to the execution context. The remote library knows nothing about any windows belonging to programs that are communicating with it.